# How to escape double backslash Ansible

Tags: azure, powershell, ansible, escaping

I am trying to use the `ansible.windows.win_powershell` module to automate mapping a network file share to a Virtual Machine in Azure. I have the following task within my playbook:

```
 - name: "Map network file share"
      ansible.windows.win_powershell:
        script: |
          $connectTestResult = Test-NetConnection -ComputerName host.file.core.windows.net -Port 445
          if ($connectTestResult.TcpTestSucceeded) {
              # Save the password so the drive will persist on reboot
              cmd.exe /C "cmdkey /add:`"<placeholder>`" /user:`"localhost\host`" /pass:`"`""
              # Mount the drive
              New-PSDrive -Name Z -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\storageaccount.file.core.windows.net\fs" -Persist
          }
          else {
              Write-Error -Message "Unable to reach the Azure storage account via port 445. Check to make sure your organization or ISP is not blocking port 445, or use Azure P2S VPN, Azure S2S VPN, or Express Route to tunnel SMB traffic over a different port."
          }
```

My playbook however is failing on line 6 of the task:

```
New-PSDrive : The network resource type is not correct
```

The displayRoot value:

```
"DisplayRoot": "\\\\storageaccount.file.core.windows.net\\fs",
```

My assumption is that this is happening because of my double backslashes within the argument passed to `-Root` aren't being escaped. I have tried many variations:

```
"\\storageaccount.file.core.windows.net\fs"
'\\storageaccount.file.core.windows.net\fs'
`"\\storageaccount.file.core.windows.net\fs`"
\"\\storageaccount.file.core.windows.net\fs'\"
```

According to https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/user_guide/windows_usage.html I should be able to use `\"` to initialise a quote. If I paste and execute the script directly on the VM itself rather than via the run book, it works perfectly. I am obviously doing something incorrectly and wondered if someone has had this issue or can see where I am going wrong?

Comment: Are you sure it's not an authentication issue?

Comment: Yes, I remove the authentication portion from the script due to obvious security concerns.

Comment: I would try supplying it explicit credentials to `New-PSDrive` via `-Credential`. Doubling quotes amount to 1 in YAML, so if that doesnt work. I would still say its a credentials issue. Sorry, don't use Ansible myself but thought I could suggest something

Comment: If you have escaping concerns, you can use the [`template:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/6/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html) to write it to disk and then execute that. If there are genuine escaping woes, you'll at least be able to distinguish them from _output_ escaping (same story by changing [`env ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/6/plugins/callback.html))